# how to redirect a directory to an url in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect a directory to other url on my site.

but I'm confused! my `.htaccess` inside `mydir`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php


Redirect 301 /public_html/mydir    http://www.***.com/test.php


order allow,deny
allow from all
```

but when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/mydir` it shows content of it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/mydir/.htaccess` you can have this rule:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php
order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /test.php [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect every request that starts with `/mydir/` to `/test.php` on your site.

Comment: Sorry it should be `RewriteRule` , try my updated rule now.